# How to dynamically add/remove back button from a page that's already been constructed in XamarinForms.Android?

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Our team is currently implementing some UI/UX improvements to standardize how a user saves/cancels any changes made while editing data in our app; and I've got everything working except this last issue on **Android**. I have a content page that displays account information (Name, address, account #, etc) using entry controls which by default have their IsReadOnly bindings set to true. However; if a user taps an 'edit' button up in the toolbar, the user is now in 'Edit Mode'; all of the entry controls IsReadOnly bindings are set to false and the user if free to make changes.

**The problem:**
To avoid ambiguity in my save/cancel pattern, I want to dynamically remove the back button from the toolbar if the user is in 'Edit Mode', and then add it back once the user saves changes. This works perfectly fine on iOS and UWP. Android only seems to allow setting the back button ONE time at page construction using something like this:

`NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);`

[image: Android content page with back arrow present]

**Is there a fix/workaround on Android for hiding the back button on a content page that has already been constructed?**

*Currently my workaround on Android is to intercept the back button press on Android and show the user a dialog warning them they are about to lose their changes and giving them the ability to save first.*

**EDIT:** Here is the code that works on UWP/iOS. This is in my code-behind xaml.cs of the view:

```
    private void EditMeterButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ViewModel.IsChangeMeterVisible)
            ViewModel.HideChangeMeterIcon();

        HandleBackArrowVisibility();
    }

    private void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HandleBackArrowVisibility();
    }

    private void CancelButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HandleBackArrowVisibility();
    }

    private void HandleBackArrowVisibility()
    {
        if (ViewModel.showBackButton)
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
        else
        {
            if(Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.Android)
                NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);               
        }
    }
```

Comment: What was the code that worked on iOS but not on Android? When UI-related code doesn't work properly, try wrapping it in BeginInvoke: `Device.BeginInvoke( () => ... );`.

Comment: What's the version of Xamarin.Forms package on your side ? Did you do any customization on toolbar in android project ?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Solid idea but unfortunately did not work. I tried wrapping my `Navigation.SetHasBackButton(this, false);` in a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>)` which is called from the clicked event of another toolbarItem. The issue persists and still can't remove the back arrow from the toolbar.

Comment: @ColeX we are on Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012. We are using the XF tool bar that comes out of the box with a `ContentPage`. We have extended `ToolBarItem` into a custom `HideableToolBarItem` which defines an  "IsVisible" property that can by used. We do nothing custom with the back arrow though, so I don't understand why it can't be removed from a clicked event.

Answer (score 1):

You want to Hide and Show the BackButton with ButtonClicked.

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
    }
```

If you want to use it Platform Specific

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.Android:
                // do your Android assignments...
                NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
                break;
            default:
                // do your UWP & iOS assignments...
                NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
                break;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand how this works for you. I have the exact same code in my code-behind of my ContentPage which is called on the clicked event of the "Edit" button in my toolbar. I even tried making a Test button as you've done, whose clicked event calls `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);` but it will NOT remove the back arrow on Android. Only iOS and UWP

Comment: This is nothing fancy , the example is showed is on Android . You can find the project here . Show and Hide the BackButton https://github.com/borisoprit/BackButtunStackO

Comment: I update the answer if using Platform specific

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the up button (left arrow)
If so you could use

```
toolbar.NavigationIcon = null;
```